# Simplest way to load .env file with `flask run` cli command?

Tags: python, linux, flask, environment-variables

There must be a simple way to load a `.env` environment file when launching a Flask app with the cli command `flask run`. I cant find an answer anywhere they all suggest loading the variables with python which I don't want to do. I am trying to run this on a Linux machine.

Comment: I think you are looking for [load_dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pip install python-dotenv
```

Then place this in the `app.py` file

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply but I dont want to load the variables with dotenv, I want them to be loaded by flask directly from a .env file

Comment: ok. there are some alternatives here: https://prettyprinted.com/tutorials/automatically_load_environment_variables_in_flask

Comment: Hello. This did not work, for some reason. When I try to print the variable content in a statement, it does'nt show anything. Also, when configuring the database URI, it also does not load my variables inside `.env`... I posted a question about it. Tried your implementation, did'nt work.